# Getting divs next to each other when clicking on a button / JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am making a kind of storyboard where you can add and remove frames but i need to set divs next to each other, the code i now have it places the div's beneath each other. I want to make it with a loop
Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div id="storyboard">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="frame">  
      <div class="frame__outer"> 
        <div class="frame__inner"></div>
        <div class="frame__content"></div>
        <div type="button" value="fade_in" class="add__button"> + </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
_this.addClickFunction = function() {
  var i = 0;
  $('.add__button').click(function() {
      $('.frame').after('<div id="container'+(i++)+'"></div> <div class="frame__outer"> <div class="frame__inner"></div><div class="frame__content"></div></div>');
  });
};
```

Comment: i believe you need to use `$("#storyboard").append(` instead of `$('.frame').after(` which will add new container inside your storyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `append()` instead of `after()` function. This should work:

```
_this.addClickFunction = function() {
  var i = 0;
  $('.add__button').click(function() {
      $('.frame').append('<div id="container'+(i++)+'"></div> <div class="frame__outer"> <div class="frame__inner"></div><div class="frame__content"></div></div>');
  });
};
```

This works for keeping one `.frame` element and adding multiple `div`s to it of the structure:

```
<div class="container[i]">  
      <div class="frame__outer"> 
        <div class="frame__inner"></div>
        <div class="frame__content"></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! But it still keeps setting the divs beneath each other, my idea was to place them next to each other

Comment: Aaah! `div` is a block element as mentioned by @Flyer53. See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp). You can adjust this in the CSS. Try the [inline-block](http://learnlayout.com/inline-block.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to arrange elements side by side which normaly are block elements and thus are positioned underneath eachother by default use either css floats or css flexbox.

- https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thank you this works, but i need 4 divs next to each other and after that 4 divs beneath it next to each other, i hope you understand what i mean

Comment: So you just need to clear the fifth element to start a new "row". See https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/#article-header-id-2

Answer (score 1):

> i need to set divs next to each other

Try this example to add new story container to all current `.container`

```js
var i = 1;
$('.add__button').click(function() {
  i++;
  $(".container").each(function(x) {
    $(this).after('<div id="container' + x + '_' + i + '" class="container"><div class="frame"><div class="frame__outer"> <div class="frame__inner"></div><div class="frame__content">story ' + i + '</div></div></div></div>');
  });

});
```

```css
.frame__outer {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #222;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: solid 3px green;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="storyboard">
  <input type='button' value='add story' class="add__button" />
  <div id="container" class='container'>
    <div class="frame">
      <div class="frame__outer">
        <div class="frame__inner"></div>
        <div class="frame__content">story 1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```